# Inside loop condition does not match nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Inside loop condition is not getting satisfied Please guide how to get this and what is causing this ?

```
var inputDate = '2020-04-11';
var result = []
for (var l = 0; l < reports.length; l++) {
  let myReport = {}
  myReport = await req.models.myReports.findAll({
    where: {
      id: reports[l].myReportId
    }
  })


  // I am getting values in myReport[0].lastDate like : '2019-04-10', '2020-01-01', '2024-05-12'
  // As i can see last last value is greater then inputDate it should not be went through if condition that mean result should stay blank but it does allow don't know why
  if ((inputDate > myReport[0].lastDate)) {
    result.push(myReport[0].name)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since inputDate variable is a string and you're probably comparing one string to another one, it's a string comparison and not of dates, I would first parse your string as date and then compare them.

```
  var inputDate = Date.parse('2020-04-11');
    var result = []
    for (var l = 0; l < reports.length; l++) {
      let myReport = {}
      myReport = await req.models.myReports.findAll({
        where: {
          id: reports[l].myReportId
        }
      })
    
    
      // I am getting values in myReport[0].lastDate like : '2019-04-10', '2020-01-01', '2024-05-12'
      // As i can see last last value is greater then inputDate it should not be went through if condition that mean result should stay blank but it does allow don't know why
      if ((inputDate > Date.parse(myReport[0].lastDate))) {
        result.push(myReport[0].name)
      }
    
    }
```

Comment: I tried that way as well doesn't get much helped, It worked same as before

Comment: I think there is problem with loop isn't ?

Comment: you can console log both parsed values and check if they're the same you expect them to be

Comment: Yes parsing values are correct input date has like : inputDate 1601596800000 and myReport has 1727740800000 which is obviously greater it should not satisfy with condition

Comment: You much resolve this yourself then :), I am not sure why it's happening, you have unnecessary brackets in last "if"